# How expensive is a proximal operation?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, convention

In optimization, a proximal step is usually considered as cheap as a gradient step. I'm quite confused by this. Why are people taking this convention at all?

A typical proximal step indeed incurs a subroutine. For example, consider the Moreau–Yosida proximal step
$$ x_{k+1} = \arg\min_y \{ f (y) + \frac{1}{2\eta} \| x_k - y \|_2^2 \} , $$
where $\eta$ is the step size.

I think we have to use some solver to arrive at $x_{k+1}$, isn't it? If we have to call a subroutine to solve for a single proximal step, why are we taking the convention that a proximal step is as cheap as a gradient step?

**Edit 1 after @Alf's comment:** If we solve the subproblem to a fixed precision, then it's no longer a proximal step, it's a proximal step with error. If we solve the subproblem to a precision depending on $k$, then we'd get an extra term depending on $k$ in the overall convergence rate. This extra term is typically of order $O (\log k)$.

**Edit 2:** An $O (\log k)$ term is definitely not free. For convex programs, [1] achieves a $o(1/k^2)$ convergence rate via proximal operations. However, the $o(1/k^2)$ algorithm in [1] may not be as fast as an $O(1/k^2)$ gradient algorithm for smooth convex programs, since [1] uses proximal operations...

[1] Hedy Attouch and Juan Peypouquet. The rate of convergence of nesterov’s accelerated forward-backward method is actually faster than $1/k^2$. SIAM Journal on Optimization, 26(3):1824–1834, 2016

Comment: It is important to note that for $\eta$ small and $f$ convex and smooth, the objective in the inner minimization problem is smooth and strongly convex (with condition number nearly $1$ when $\eta$ is large enough), so a minimizer can be found very cheaply. Depending on the overall application, it can therefore make sense to think of this inner loop as basically free.

Comment: @Alf. If you solve it to a fixed precision, then it's no longer a proximal step, it's a proximal step with error. If you solve it to a precision depending on $k$, then you'd get an extra $\log k$ term in the convergence rate.

Comment: @Alf Please see my Edit 2 above. the cost of proximal operations is important.

Comment: The proximal operator is definitely not considered to be cheap. However, for some functions it can be solved in a close form. Typically in a ML scenario you regularize problem to solve a new optimization problem : $\min f +g$. If $\textrm{prox}_g$ is easily computed (e.g. $g = || \cdot||_1$), then you can solve it by applying a gradient step on $f$ and a proximal step on $g$. In this case, it is as cheap as just using gradient descent on $f$.

Comment: Adding to @Alf comment, if $f$ is $C^1$ with Lipschitz-continuous gradients (or more generally weakly-convex) then it is known that for $\eta$ small enough, the minimization problem in the prox operator will be convex. Thus, we can solve a sequence of convex operators (which can be easier than to solve a non-convex one), which might be interesting from a theoretical/practical point. Doesn't mean that the proximal step will be cheap though.

Comment: @J.Doe Thanks. That's an important case where the proximal operation is cheap. But there are other important cases where the proximal step can be very expensive. Let $g$ be a function that is 0 within a convex set $C$ and $\infty$ outside of it. We can pick a crazy convex set $C$ so that projection onto $C$ is very expensive. Based on what I learned from the literature (by reputable researchers in good venues), the convergence rate is in a lot of cases measured by how many proximal steps are needed, and the complexity of the proximal step is not discussed... That's weird...

Comment: The prox operator is clearly not as cheap, I don't know in which community you have seen this but it is not like that. That being said, specifically for convex smooth functions you can implement an inexact accelerated proximal point method in a way that the total complexity of the method is like nesterov's accelerated GD, by using only 5 iterations of gradient descent on the prox subproblem https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.11271 And there are other more general reductions that do not incur more than a constant penalty for randomized algorithms https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.08627.pdf